# How to serialize just the Avro binary encoding without the fingerprint or schema

Tags: rust, avro

We have a system where we just need the Avro raw bytes, without the *single object encoding* header, and also not the Avro container format. [Just the bytes please](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/spec.html#binary_encoding). We pass the identifier of the schema to the deserializer via another path.

I can't find the correct call in the [Avro Rust sources or documentation](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/rust/avro/src/writer.rs)

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out to be pretty trivial with `avro_rs`

[`to_avro_datum(schema, avro_record)`](https://github.com/strmprivacy/rust-driver/blob/master/src/client/sender_service.rs#L28)

As said above, one needs to identify the *writer schema*, which in the above link was done via an http header. Internally we use both Confluent and single object encoding to keep the data together with the schema.

Comment: Did you, by any chance, also find a way to parse an Avro message without header and container format? I'm trying to parse a message from a Kafka topic.

Comment: Quite simple:

`let value = avro_rs::from_avro_datum(  &schema,  &buffer,  None)`
[Documentation](https://docs.rs/avro-rs/latest/avro_rs/fn.from_avro_datum.html)

You need to know the writer schema in some way. At strmprivacy.io we use different forms (http headers, Confluent wire format and Avro fingerprint).

Comment: `avro_rs::from_avro_datum` was used [in this codebase](https://github.com/redwhitemike/DiffPriv/blob/d6429fbeea7d3843e4b4168645c3bb6ca8af7fb2/src/kafka/kafka_service.rs#L23). The code skips the Confluent wire format (5 bytes) and then directly deserializes with the already known writer schema.

Answer (score -1):

Because in this code it's not possible. `Writer` constructor automatically serialises schema into the buffer. The only way I can think of is to write our own `W` that would automatically ditch everything we don't need.